# JSON Fields with Panda DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, google-colaboratory

I'm using Python (google colb) and I have a json dataframe with some fields like:

`[{'ActedBy': ['team'], 'ActedAt': '2022-03-07T22:43:46Z', 'Status': 'Completed', 'LAB': 'No'}]`

I need to get the "ActedAt" in order to get the "date" how can I get this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of dictionaries. First, grab a dictionary from the array by index, then proceed to get the `ActedAt` property. Something like this:

```py
json = [{'ActedBy': ['team'], 'ActedAt': '2022-03-07T22:43:46Z', 'Status': 'Completed', 'LAB': 'No'}]
# index into a variable for explicit readability
index = 0
# get the date you want
date = json[index]['ActedAt']
print(date)
```